# lookup compose in material table in react

Tags: javascript, material-ui, jsobject

Im getting a string array as response from API for lookup like `['India', 'Sri Lanka']`

I need to pass this as parameter to material react table column as LOV as below

```
 { field: "countries", title: "Countries", lookup: { India: 'India', China: 'China' } },
```

I tried transforming countries string array using map to pass the lookup in correct format, but not able to set key correctly

```
    transformLookupData = (strArr) => {
        return strArr.map((str, index) => {
            return {str: str}
        });
    }
```

Please let me know your answers.

In short, I need to convert this array `['India', 'Sri Lanka']` to `{ India: 'India', China: 'China' }`

Answer (score 0):

You are going the right way, to use dynamic object key, wrap it in square bracket

```js
{ [str]: str }
```

```js
const data = ["India", "Sri Lanka"]

const transformLookupData = (strArr) => strArr.map((str) => ({ [str]: str }))

console.log(transformLookupData(data))
```

Comment: Its Working..Thanks for your quick response